# Floating-point issue in R

Tags: c#, r, double, sum

I am doing `colSums(x)` of a matrix `x` in `R`

and to compare results I do it `C#`

the matrix has `1000 rows and 25 columns` ans is something like:

```
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.645,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.351,2.332,2.643,1.698,1.687,1.698,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.445,0.431,0.444,0.440,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.648,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.637,2.332,2.649,1.695,1.687,1.695,1.720,1.744,0.592,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.443,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.637,2.334,2.643,1.696,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.446,0.429,1.0
0.437,0.501,3.625,3.626,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.353,2.334,2.642,1.730,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.444,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.626,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.640,2.334,2.639,1.696,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.592,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.441,0.429,1.0
0.439,0.498,3.626,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.633,2.334,2.645,1.705,1.686,1.694,1.719,1.744,0.589,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.446,0.431,0.444,0.444,0.430,1.0
0.440,5.000,3.627,3.628,5.000,2.919,3.028,2.346,2.330,2.638,1.727,1.684,1.692,1.714,1.745,0.588,0.501,0.492,0.504,0.451,0.433,0.446,0.444,0.432,1.0
0.444,5.021,3.631,3.634,5.000,2.919,5.000,2.626,2.327,2.638,1.698,1.680,1.688,1.709,1.740,0.595,0.500,0.491,0.503,0.453,0.436,0.448,0.444,0.436,1.0
0.451,5.025,3.635,3.639,5.000,2.920,3.027,2.620,2.323,2.632,1.706,1.673,1.681,1.703,0.753,0.595,0.499,0.491,0.502,0.457,0.440,0.453,0.454,0.442,2.0
0.458,5.022,3.640,3.644,5.000,2.922,5.000,2.346,2.321,2.628,1.688,1.666,1.674,1.696,0.744,0.590,0.496,0.490,0.498,0.462,0.444,0.458,0.461,0.449,2.0
0.465,0.525,3.646,3.670,5.000,2.923,5.000,2.611,2.315,2.631,1.674,1.658,1.666,1.688,0.735,0.593,0.495,0.488,0.497,0.467,0.449,0.462,0.469,0.457,2.0
0.473,0.533,3.652,3.676,5.000,2.925,5.000,2.607,2.310,2.623,1.669,1.651,1.659,1.684,0.729,0.578,0.496,0.487,0.498,0.469,0.454,0.467,0.476,0.465,2.0
0.481,0.544,3.658,3.678,5.000,2.926,5.000,2.606,2.303,2.619,1.668,1.643,1.651,1.275,0.723,0.581,0.495,0.486,0.497,0.477,0.459,0.472,0.484,0.472,2.0
0.484,0.544,3.661,3.665,5.000,2.928,5.000,2.321,2.304,5.022,1.647,1.639,1.646,1.270,0.757,0.623,0.493,0.484,0.495,0.480,0.461,0.474,0.485,0.476,2.0
0.484,0.532,3.669,3.662,2.945,2.926,5.000,2.326,2.306,2.620,1.648,1.639,1.646,1.270,0.760,0.533,0.493,0.483,0.494,0.507,0.461,0.473,0.486,0.476,2.0
0.482,0.520,3.685,3.664,2.952,2.927,5.000,2.981,2.307,2.329,1.650,1.640,1.644,1.268,0.757,0.533,0.492,0.482,0.492,0.513,0.459,0.474,0.485,0.474,2.0
0.481,0.522,3.682,3.661,2.955,2.927,2.957,2.984,1.700,2.622,1.651,1.641,1.645,1.272,0.761,0.530,0.492,0.482,0.492,0.513,0.462,0.486,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.480,0.525,3.694,3.664,2.948,2.926,2.950,2.995,1.697,2.619,1.651,1.642,1.646,1.269,0.762,0.530,0.493,0.482,0.492,0.516,0.462,0.486,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.481,0.515,5.018,3.664,2.956,2.927,2.947,2.993,1.697,2.622,1.651,1.641,1.645,1.269,0.765,0.592,0.489,0.482,0.495,0.531,0.462,0.499,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.479,5.000,3.696,3.661,2.953,2.927,2.944,2.993,1.702,2.622,1.649,1.642,1.645,1.269,0.812,0.588,0.489,0.481,0.491,0.510,0.462,0.481,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.480,0.506,5.019,3.665,2.941,2.929,2.945,2.981,1.700,2.616,1.652,1.642,1.645,1.271,0.814,0.643,0.491,0.480,0.493,0.524,0.461,0.469,0.484,0.473,2.0
0.479,5.000,5.019,3.661,2.943,2.930,2.942,2.996,1.698,2.312,1.653,1.642,1.644,1.274,0.811,0.617,0.491,0.479,0.491,0.575,0.461,0.465,0.484,0.473,2.0
0.479,5.000,5.020,3.662,2.945,2.931,2.942,2.997,1.700,2.313,1.654,1.642,1.644,1.270,0.908,0.616,0.490,0.478,0.489,0.503,0.460,0.460,0.478,0.473,1.0
0.481,0.508,5.021,3.660,2.954,2.936,2.946,2.966,1.705,2.313,1.654,1.643,1.643,1.270,1.689,0.678,0.493,0.477,0.483,0.497,0.467,0.459,0.476,0.473,1.0
0.486,0.510,0.522,3.662,2.958,2.938,2.939,2.627,1.707,2.314,1.659,1.643,1.639,1.665,1.702,0.696,0.516,0.476,0.477,0.547,0.465,0.457,0.470,0.474,1.0
```

R displays this after colSums(x):

```
1463.739 2286.797 2624.315 2798.060 3003.597 2985.547 3322.785 2670.472 3261.508 3031.385 2614.597 1981.419 2185.030 2252.883 2320.446 1273.813 1020.814  907.378 1096.219 1044.184 1001.622 1915.268 1514.871 1515.182 2297.000
```

which is correct but the decimal point is moved 3 positions 
I know this because in C# solution I get:

```
 1: 1463739
 2: 2286797
 3: 2624315
 4: 2798060
 5: 3003597
 6: 2985547
 7: 3322785
 8: 2670472
 9: 3261508
 10: 3031385
 11: 2614597
 12: 1981419
 13: 2185030
 14: 2252883
 15: 2320446
 16: 1273813
 17: 1020814
 18: 907378
 19: 1096219
 20: 1044184
 21: 1001622
 22: 1915268
 23: 1514871
 24: 1515182
 25: 22970
```

why is this happening?
to read dataset I do

```
x <- read.csv( "C:\\x.txt", header=T , row.names=NULL)
```

in C#

```
double[]  L  = new double[25];
for ( i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
   array[i] += reader.GetDouble(i);
}
```

The correct values are those in `C#`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your R code reads `colSums` and not `colMeans`. with 1000 rows, that would explain it.

Comment: well, I am sure, to have put colSums, also in C# I get the same numbers but only the decimal point is moved...

Comment: with 1000 numbers colSums(x) = 1000*colMeans(x), so it was worth a guess. Also, you didn't tell us which value is correct, the R value or the C# value.

Comment: The correct values are those in C#, I know this because I have worked with those numbers and C# Solution is nice, and R is almost right..., also if I do colMeans(x) I get
 
`1.463739 2.286797 2.624315 2.798060 3.003597 2.985547 3.322785 2.670472 3.261508 3.031385 2.614597 1.981419 2.185030 
2.252883 2.320446 1.273813 1.020814 0.907378 1.096219 1.044184 1.001622 1.915268 1.514871 1.515182 2.297000 `

Comment: Are you **SURE** the C# values are the correct ones? From your data it seems that the values are around 0-5 and 1000 of them would sum up to somewhere between 0 and 5000 as R did - not 3 million as you get in C#...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check the `CultureInfo`, may be that . rappresent thousand separator not decimal separator in your `Culture`.

Comment: What would be the correct CultureInfo, how to know this.... Instead of `1463739, 2286797   I get  1463.739 2286.797` in R

Comment: If the C# values are fine then you need to tweak the R locale rather than the C# locale.

Comment: Read the help file on `read.csv` for how to select the decimal indicator.  And I bet you can solve your problem by taking a look at some of the actual values in your matrix `x` .  To be safe, also type `typeof(x)` and if you don't get "double" for an answer there's something wrong with your data as loaded.